# Fixed width file to sql server wide table

Tags: sql-server, fixed-width

I have a text file with Data in fixed width. The text file contains ID, Data,State. ID is just a INT. State has 2 CHAR statename. Data is the info of Companies that are registered in that State.

To put them in SQL server tables, I first dumped the text file to a SQLServer table called dbo.rawcompanyinfo_delimited

**Note:** for ease of explaining I have shown only 4 columns in Data column. It has 500 columns.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.rawcompanyinfo_delimited(ID smallint NOT NULL, Data VARCHAR(MAX) NULL, State CHAR(2));

INSERT INTO dbo.rawcompanyinfo_delimited(100,'ABCINC    111  333.5 USD','PA')
INSERT INTO dbo.rawcompanyinfo_delimited(200,'APPLE     213  333.5 USD','PA')
INSERT INTO dbo.rawcompanyinfo_delimited(300,'BTEC      100  123.5 USD','PA')
INSERT INTO dbo.rawcompanyinfo_delimited(400,'S INC     123  333.0 USD','PA')
INSERT INTO dbo.rawcompanyinfo_delimited(500,'B INC     145  123.2 USD','PA')
```

I also have a mapping table that tells me Startingposition,length and Columnnames stored in map.CompaniesLenInfo

```
CREATE TABLE map.CompaniesLenInfo(Startingposition int not null, Length int not null, columnnames varchar(100) not null)
insert into map.CompaniesLenInfo(1,10,CompanyName)
insert into map.CompaniesLenInfo(11,3,CompanyID)
insert into map.CompaniesLenInfo(15,5,TotalIncome)
insert into map.CompaniesLenInfo(21,3,Currency)
```

I wrote a nested cursor that loops through map.CompaniesLenInfo and then through dbo.rawcompanyinfo_delimited and store the results in a table.
like below

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.output(ID INT , CompanyName VARCHAR(10),CompanyID VARCHAR(3),TotalIncome VARCHAR(5),Currency VARCHAR(3)) ;
INSERT INTO dbo.output(100,'ABCINC','111','333.5','USD','PA')
INSERT INTO dbo.output(200,'APPLE','213','333.5', 'USD','PA')
INSERT INTO dbo.output(300,'BTEC'      ,'100',  '123.5', 'USD','PA')
INSERT INTO dbo.output(400,'S INC'     ,'123',  '333.0', 'USD','PA')
INSERT INTO dbo.output(500,'B INC'     ,'145',  '123.2', 'USD','PA')
```

---

```
DECLARE @ID INT,@StartPosition INT,@Len INT;
DECLARE @Data NVARCHAR(MAX), @ColumnName VARCHAR(100),@Val VARCHAR(MAX),@CompanyID CHAR(9),@State_Code  VARCHAR(2);
DECLARE @Currency VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @FinCursor AS CURSOR;

DECLARE @ParsingCursor AS CURSOR;
SET @FinCursor=CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT ID,Data 
FROM map.CompaniesLenInfo WHERE State='PA';
OPEN @FinCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM @FinCursor INTO @ID,@Data;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN


  SET @ParsingCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT StartPosition,Length,columnnames
  FROM dbo.rawcompanyinfo_delimited;
  OPEN @ParsingCursor;
  FETCH NEXT FROM @ParsingCursor INTO @StartPosition, @Len, @ColumnName;
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
      BEGIN
           SET @Val = SUBSTRING(@Data,@StartPosition, @Len);
           /* Not sure how to insert into dbo.output*/

          FETCH NEXT FROM @ParsingCursor INTO @StartPosition, @Len, @ColumnName;
      END

  CLOSE @ParsingCursor;
  DEALLOCATE @ParsingCursor;


FETCH NEXT FROM @FinCursor INTO @ID,@Data;

END
CLOSE @FinCursor;
DEALLOCATE @FinCursor;
```

How can I insert as a wide table.Can anybody suggest any other method that could be faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample using PIVOT:

CREATE TABLE dbo.rawcompanyinfo_delimited(ID smallint NOT NULL, Data VARCHAR(MAX) NULL, State CHAR(2));

```
INSERT INTO dbo.rawcompanyinfo_delimited(id,data,State)values(100,'ABCINC    111  333.5 USD','PA')
INSERT INTO dbo.rawcompanyinfo_delimited(id,data,State)values(200,'APPLE     213  333.5 USD','PA')
INSERT INTO dbo.rawcompanyinfo_delimited(id,data,State)values(300,'BTEC      100  123.5 USD','PA')
INSERT INTO dbo.rawcompanyinfo_delimited(id,data,State)values(400,'S INC     123  333.0 USD','PA')
INSERT INTO dbo.rawcompanyinfo_delimited(id,data,State)values(500,'B INC     145  123.2 USD','PA')

CREATE TABLE CompaniesLenInfo(Startingposition int not null, Length int not null, columnnames varchar(100) not null)
insert into CompaniesLenInfo(Startingposition,Length,columnnames)VALUES(1,10,'CompanyName')
insert into CompaniesLenInfo(Startingposition,Length,columnnames)VALUES(11,3,'CompanyID')
insert into CompaniesLenInfo(Startingposition,Length,columnnames)VALUES(15,5,'TotalIncome')
insert into CompaniesLenInfo(Startingposition,Length,columnnames)VALUES(21,3,'Currency')

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT r.ID,r.State,SUBSTRING(r.Data,ci.Startingposition,ci.Length) AS val,ci.columnnames 
    FROM rawcompanyinfo_delimited AS r,CompaniesLenInfo AS ci
) AS t PIVOT(MAX(val) FOR columnnames IN (CompanyName,CompanyID,TotalIncome,Currency) ) p
```

```
+-----+-------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+
| ID  | State | CompanyName | CompanyID | TotalIncome | Currency |
+-----+-------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+
| 100 | PA    | ABCINC      | 111       |  333.       |  US      |
| 200 | PA    | APPLE       | 213       |  333.       |  US      |
| 300 | PA    | BTEC        | 100       |  123.       |  US      |
| 400 | PA    | S INC       | 123       |  333.       |  US      |
| 500 | PA    | B INC       | 145       |  123.       |  US      |
+-----+-------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the command line tool `bcp`, Bulk Copy Program.  bcp will parse and load your data.  You will need to define a "format file" to define where your fixed width columns start and stop.  If you can get the data delimited by another character (such as ~) then it's easier to define column delimiters and row terminators.

Here's the doc reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-bulk-import-data-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a cursor. To load the data from your raw data table into the output table, you can use a single (maybe a bit lengthy if you have 500 columns) INSERT SELECT statement:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.output(ID,CompanyName,CompanyID,TotalIncome,Currency)
SELECT r.ID, 
      (SELECT Substring(r.Data, m.startingposition, m.length)
         FROM map.CompaniesLenInfo AS m
        WHERE m.columnnames = 'CompanyName'),
      ...
      (SELECT Substring(r.Data, m.startingposition, m.length)
         FROM map.CompaniesLenInfo AS m
        WHERE m.columnnames = 'Currency')
  FROM dbo.rawcompanyinfo_delimited AS r
```